# faster way of executing SELECT ... WHERE id IN ... in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I am in the middle of a uni project, when I discovered a huge problem with my database. Using wamp, and a massive (300Mb) database but with just a few tables my queries are very slow :( All tables are created with MyISAM engine. All settings are on default, I am not experienced in any optimisation. I will need to think of some better way to do it, but for now my question is what is the best substitute for the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `payments` WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
```

I can't use left join or any similar solution I have found here, because those IDs (1,2,3,4,5, ...) are not coming from the database. User select the payments he wants to delete, and on the next screen payment details are displayed.

FYI, payments table has more than a million records :)

Comment: Do you have an index on the `id` column? That would probably help most (for this query)

Comment: 300Mb is not massive. Even for an application running on MSWindows. Maybe if you showed the the structure of the table/indexes, the mysqld settings and provided an EXPLAIN plan we'd be able to advise. And just because the data comes from a user doesn't mean it can't go into the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a continuos range:

```
SELECT * FROM payments WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

If the range is disjoint:
Create an indexed `memory` table with the values in it.

```
CREATE TABLE mem_table (
  pk unsigned integer primary key
) ENGINE = MEMORY;

INSERT INTO mem_table (pk) VALUES (1),(2),...,(10);

SELECT p.* FROM payments p
INNER JOIN mem_table m ON (m.pk = p.id);
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html

**PS**
Make sure you have an index on `id` (this should really be the primary key).

Comment: Oh, I'm afraid I don't know anything about memory tables. I will play with it in the next few days, and will let you know if this works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yup, this was enough. And I have learned now what the memory tables are for :) Thanks a lot.